# Не открывается файл пайтон через консолль

Tags: python, cmd

[image]
Ввожу название файла с предпиской python по нужному пути, где лежит сам файл, но он отказывается открываться и пишет данную ошибку

Comment: Вводить команду python нужно не в python-интерпретатор, а в командную строку без запуска питона

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать пункт в контекстном меню системы, чтобы запускать файлы python без геморроя. Создайте на рабочем столе файл `cmd.reg`, откройте в Sublime Text и скопируйте туда текст ниже.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Run CMD]
"Icon"="cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Run CMD\command]
@="cmd.exe"
```

После этого сохраните файл и откройте его двойным кликом. Нажмите Да и ОК. Удалите файл.
Теперь при нажатии ПКМ по любому файлу вы сможете запустить командную строку с текущим каталогом (пункт Run CMD), для запуска python файла нужно только ввести имя.

А ответ на вопрос уже есть в комментариях к вопросу.